# How to make MacBook notifications fade by themselves?

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur

Currently, notifications appear in the top right corner, and never go away by themselves.

How to make notifications fade after 30 seconds?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what type of notification it is.

Alerts stay until you dismiss them.
Banners stay a short while, then auto-close.

[image]

This is Mojave. Big Sur is similar, just with some slight visual differences.